# Using Selenium through python how can I get the name of the button?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
<li id="add-to-cart" class="">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" class="primary" name="add-to-cart">
</li>
```

I want to print value

Output: `Add to Cart`

Comment: Update your question with code you've tried so far

Comment: You want to print `value` or `name` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution:
first get elements inside < li> (Maybe there will be more than one):

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@id='add-to-cart']//input")

for e in elements:
    print(e.get_attribute("name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Selenium docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html):

- find the button element using one of the `find_element_by...` methods on a driver (or on a parent WebElement)
- read the name of the button or value of an input using `.get_attribute(attribute_name)`
- read the text using property `.text`

Comment: Thanks for your answer
It is giving error when I use .text
It give output 0 when I print without .text